# RSolve not evaluating when given my system of recurrence equations

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of recurrences with `RSolve`:

```
RSolve[
  {(1 - q^n) A[n] == 
    q^(3 n - 1) B[n - 1] + q^(2 n + 1) A[n - 1] + 
    q^(4 n - 2) A[n - 2] + q^(4 n - 2) B[n - 2],
   B[n] == 
     q^(n + 1) A[n - 1] - q^(5 n - 5) A[n - 3] - q^(5 n - 5) B[n - 3],
   A[0] == 1, A[1] == q^3/(1 - q), A[2] == q^6/((1 - q) (1 - q^2)), 
   B[0] == 0, B[1] == q^2, B[2] == q^6/(1 - q)},
  {A[n], B[n]}, n]
```

But the output is just the same as my input. I tried with initial conditions at for `A` and `B` at 1, 2, 3 (to avoid the singularity of `1 - q^0`, but it also does not return anything.

Does this mean that Mathematica cannot solve this system?

Comment: **ONLY can solve** for `q=1`: `RSolve[{(1 - q^n) A[n] == 
     q^(3 n - 1) B[n - 1] + q^(2 n + 1) A[n - 1] + 
      q^(4 n - 2) A[n - 2] + q^(4 n - 2) B[n - 2], 
    B[n] == q^(n + 1) A[n - 1] - q^(5 n - 5) A[n - 3] - 
      q^(5 n - 5) B[n - 3]} /. q -> 1, {A[n], B[n]}, 
  n] // FullSimplify`

Comment: at $q=1$ the system is not defined as the initial conditions blow up. In fact it is easy to see that $A[n]$ times $(q)_n$ is a polynomial and $B[n]$ times $(q)_{n-1}$ is a polynomial. I tried writing the recurrence for these products (multiplying accordingly the system above) and also didn' t get a solution